# Можно ли к форме подключить еще один send.php??? не будет ли конфликта? мне надо что бы в базу данных отправлялось в определеные поля по имени

Tags: php, javascript, html, modx

Получается форма обратной связи Тикет(модх) там черт ногу сломит не могу понять ее( и вот можно ли обычный файл пхп подключить еще для отправки всего ? а так еще один для получения в админки что бы отобразить?

```html
<h4 id="comment-new-link">
 {if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Оставить вопрос</a>
 {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Сұрақ қойыңыз</a>
 {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Leave a question</a>
 {/if}
</h4>

<div id="comment-form-placeholder">
 <form id="comment-form" action="" method="post" class="well">
  <div id="comment-preview-placeholder"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="thread" value="[[+thread]]" />
  <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0" />

  <div class="form-group">
   {if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    <label for="comment-name">ФИО</label>
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    <label for="comment-name">Аты-жөні</label>
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
    <label for="comment-name">Full Name</label>
   {/if}
   <input type="text" name="name" value="[[+name]]" id="comment-name" class="form-control" />
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="comment-email">[[%ticket_comment_email]]</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" value="[[+email]]" id="comment-email" class="form-control" />
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
   {if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    <label for="comment-name">ИИН</label>
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    <label for="comment-name">ЖСН</label>
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
    <label for="comment-name">IIN</label>
   {/if}
   <input type="text" name="number" value="[[+number]]" id="comment-number" class="form-control" />
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   {if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    <label for="comment-name">Сфера</label>
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    <label for="comment-name">Сфера</label>
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
    <label for="comment-name">Sphere</label>
   {/if}
   <br>
   <script>$(document).ready(function(){
     var $optgroups = $('#subcategory > optgroup');
     
     $("#category").on("change",function(){
       var selectedVal = this.value;
       
       $('#subcategory').html($optgroups.filter('[label="'+selectedVal+'"]'));
    });  
   });</script>
   
   
   <select id="category">
   <option value="{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Сфера тепло и электроэнергетики
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Жылу және электр энергетикасы саласы
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Sphere of heat and electric power industry
   {/if}">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Сфера тепло и электроэнергетики
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Жылу және электр энергетикасы саласы
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Sphere of heat and electric power industry
   {/if}</option>
   <option value="{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Сфера использования атомной энергии
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Атом энергиясын пайдалану саласы
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
    Sphere of use of atomic energy
   {/if}">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Сфера использования атомной энергии
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Атом энергиясын пайдалану саласы
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
    Sphere of use of atomic energy
   {/if}</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   {if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    <label for="comment-name">Категории</label>
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    <label for="comment-name">Санаттар</label>
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
    <label for="comment-name">Categories</label>
   {/if}<br>
   <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
    <optgroup label="{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Сфера тепло и электроэнергетики
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Жылу және электр энергетикасы саласы
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Sphere of heat and electric power industry
   {/if}">
       <option value="test1">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Общая
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Жалпы ақпарат
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   General information
   {/if}</option>
       <option value="test11">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Законодательство
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Заңнама
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Legislation
   {/if}</option>
       <option value="test12">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Аккредитация
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Аккредитация
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Accreditation
   {/if}</option>
       <option value="test13">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Теплоэнергетика
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Жылу энергетикасы
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Heat power engineering
   {/if}</option>
       <option value="test14">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Электроэнергетика
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Энергетика
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Power engineering
   {/if}</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup id="B" label="{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Сфера использования атомной энергии
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Атом энергиясын пайдалану саласы
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
    Sphere of use of atomic energy
   {/if}">
       <option value="test2">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Общая
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Жалпы ақпарат
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   General information
   {/if}</option>
       <option value="test21">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Законодательство
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Заңнама
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Legislation
   {/if}</option>
       <option value="test22">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Лицензирование
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Лицензиялау
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Licensing
   {/if}</option>
       <option value="test23">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Импорт - экспорт
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Импорт - экспорт
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Import Export
   {/if}</option>
       <option value="test24">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Учет ИИИ
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Accounting IRS
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Бухгалтерлік есеп IRS
   {/if}</option>
     </optgroup>
    </select>   
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="comment-editor"></label>
   <textarea name="text" id="comment-editor" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>

  [[+captcha]]
  <label style="color:black;" for="comment-name">{if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    Отображать на сайте
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    Сайтта көрсету
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
   Display on site?
   {/if}</label><br>
   <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1"
       name="res" value="disp">
      <label style="color:black;" for="contactChoice1">Да</label>
  
      <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2"
       name="res" value="nodisp">
      <label style="color:black;" for="contactChoice2">Нет</label>
  <div class="form-actions">
   {if $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'ru'}
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default preview" value="Предпросмотр" title="Ctrl + Enter" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" value="Отправить" title="Ctrl + Shift + Enter" />
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'kz'}
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default preview" value="Алдын ала қарау" title="Ctrl + Enter" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" value="Жіберу" title="Ctrl + Shift + Enter" />
   {elseif $_modx->config.cultureKey == 'en'}
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default preview" value="Preview" title="Ctrl + Enter" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" value="Send" title="Ctrl + Shift + Enter" />
   {/if}
   <span class="time"></span>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>

<!--tickets_captcha
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="comment-captcha" id="comment-captcha">[[+captcha]]</label>
 <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" id="comment-captcha" class="form-control" />
 <span class="error"></span>
</div>
-->
```

Comment: Странная у вас локализация. Обычно она реализуется через фильтр?
 что-то вроде: `{{'Send'|trans}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта:

1. Вы используете отправку формы через аттрибут action="", от
   отправляется на необходимый вам адрес, на том адресе вы можете
   переслать данные на следующий адрес, но все манипуляции с пришедшими
   данными можно осуществить в одном скрипте.
2. Вы используете js отправку формы, например через ajax, вы можете
   отправить на его на сколько угодно адресов и дальше редиректить
   юзера если необходимо

Comment: Мне надо к определным полям в базе данных отправить какой метод лучше?

Comment: В вашем случае через ajax будет лучше